# Could 'one side of the doorway' be used for referring to either the outside or inside of the doorway?

Tags: word-meaning

There are two people in the following picture.

[image]

It seems the woman is going out of the room and the man is trying to comfort the woman.

I guess it make sense to use "the man in the doorway" to describe the man's location.

The following is an excerpt from “The Knight at Dawn” by Mary Pope Osborne.

> Jack waved back. He waited till the boys and horses disappeared inside the stable. Then he dashed to the well.
> “I’m going to find the music!” whispered Annie. “Are you coming?”
> “Okay,” Jack said with a sigh.
> They tiptoed together across the cobblestones. Then they slipped into the entrance of the castle. Noise and music came from a bright room in
> front of them. They stood on **one side** of the doorway and peeked in.
> “The feast in the Great Hall!” whispered Jack.
> He held his breath as he stared in awe. A giant fireplace blazed at one end of the noisy room. Antlers and rugs hung on the stone walls. Flowers covered the floor. Boys in short dresses carried huge trays of food. Dogs were fighting over bones under the tables. People in bright clothes and funny hats strolled among the crowd. Some played funny-shaped guitars.
> Some tossed balls in the air. Some balanced swords on their hands. Men
> and women dressed in capes and furs sat at long, crowded wooden
> tables.
> “I wonder which one is the knight,” said Jack.
> “I don’t know,” whispered Annie. “But they’re eating with their fingers.”
> Suddenly, someone shouted behind them.

Assume the man is inside the bedroom, does it make sense to say "the man is standing on the inside of the doorway while the woman is standing on the outside of the doorway"? If yes, the book doesn't clearly narrate which side of the doorway Annie and Jack stand on. they might stand on either the outside or inside of the doorway. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: I'd guess "They stood on one side of the doorway and peeked in" means either the left side or the right side. You could imagine them together, maybe one above the other, looking around the edge of the door.

Comment: If they are 'peeking in[to]' the room, I would assume that they are still outside the door (I agree that 'one side' means left or right, not inside or outside). In the picture, the woman has evidently just walked through the door and the man is standing in the doorway (or walking through it, as he has one foot raised).

Comment: No, in your text they are on the outside of the bright room looking into it from the doorway into it. But I suppose you are writing this? "They stood at the doorway and peeked in."

Answer (score 0):

When thinking about the "inside" and "outside" of the doorway, consider the door to be *part of the room*.

So:

"Inside the doorway" is inside the room.
"Outside the doorway" is outside the room.

"**The hosts of the party were waiting for us just on *inside of the doorway*.**"
(The hosts are definitely inside the room the door opens into.)

"**Who is the man outside my doorway?**" (The man is outside of the room the door opens into.)

"One side of the doorway" can mean either the inside or the outside, in your passage is it the outside - since they are "peeking in".  "One side of the doorway" is not very commonly used.  In context in your passage, it emphasizes that Jack and Annie were together, and apart from the activity inside the room.

If, on the other hand, you hear "in the doorway", that does indicate the space in-between the inside and the outside of the room.

**"He paused in the doorway, and found he was unable to decide if he wanted to enter or leave.**"  (The person described is in the space between the room and what is outside the doorway).

Answer (score -1):

Neither person is "standing". Both are obviously moving, as shown by their feet and posture. The woman, for instance, cannot be standing in one place, since she is leaning so far that she would fall over.

Ordinarily, a doorway, as opposed to a door, doesn't have an inside or outside, it has a left or right. In your example, I would understand the two kids to be hiding at one side of the doorway, peeking around the edge. Questions of in/out would be addressed by something like "peeking into the room".

Comment: I'm sorry but my doors have an inside or outside. Unless they are just inside doors.

Comment: Thank you. Would you please take a look at my quoted narration "They stood on one side of the doorway and peeked in"?

Comment: @Lambie - yes, and my statement, "as opposed to a door" made the same point. You might say, "Someone was banging on the outside of the door", but "Someone was banging on the outside of the doorway" would be unusual.

Comment: Of course "inside the doorway" and "outside the doorway" are real, meaningful place phrases.  This is very common English.   On the other hand, I have never heard "left" and "Right" used idiomatically with  a doorway, and I can find any use that does not literally just describe the space to the left or the right of the door.

Comment: Further, it doesn't matter if the people in the picture are moving or not, one is still "inside the doorway" (because he is inside the room), and one is still "outside the doorway", because she is outside the room.